# Control Spotify background music in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, spotify

I'm making an app that uses gestures to change the current background music e.g Pause, Skip, etc. Currently I can do this fine for music that is playing through the native `MPMusicPlayerController` class.

However I am unable to control the music when it is coming from Spotify (or other music playing apps for that matter). I believe this is to do with Apple's sandboxing policy between apps.

I'm not too hopeful, but does anyone know a way to trigger a universal music control notification? Something similar to what must happen on the iOS lockscreen when background music is playing? All my research tells me this almost definitely done through a private API, but am unable to get confirmation.

Alternatively, is there any Spotify specific way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is No.

You can't get any information/Notifications about other apps, even regarding what's now playing.

As you wondered, it's all regarding the Sandboxing policy of Apple.